# What is the best way to organize code for a simple game for X11 and Win32

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns

I'm implementing a simple game for an assignment that would ideally run both on Unix(using X11's graphics context) and Windows(using Window's GDI) with both of their window manager. What would be the best way to structure the code so that I can simply plug in the correct C++ class to make it run on each OS?

More specifically, how do I completely separate out the graphics & windowing component out of the actual game component? (e.g. use observer pattern so that the game component would observe  on the platform-specific windowing component for user input, create a common interface for loading/displaying sprite, create another common interface for repainting, etc). Who should be responsible for copying and pasting each object's graphics/device context to the main screen's gc/dc? Which component should contain the main eventloop/window callback(if it's the main component, then do I need two versions of the main component for each platform?) Also, how do I make each object(e.g. blocks, characters etc) hold platform specific datatypes(`gc` for X11 and `DC` for GDI)?

The two basic requirements are that I can only use X11 and GDI and it cannot be multithreaded.

Comment: Windowing system? That's not multi-threaded? I see...

Comment: Why would blocks and characters need to store a device context?  Anyway, have you considered SDL?

Comment: @BenVoigt please enlighten me on this one. I'm actually not even sure which component should actually hold the gc/dc for each sprite. Do I need a resource manager that would return the loaded gc/dc for each object that would hand it over to graphics manager which would then copy and paste it to the main screen gc/dc? And using any other library other than Xlib and GDI isn't allowed...

Comment: @user1054465: Normally you'd have a rendering engine that owns the gc/dc and exposes primitives.  You can have each object know how to render itself (and consume the rendering engine) or have a master renderer that walks the object list and renders everything.  The latter is potentially much faster, because the master renderer can do z-order sorting and culling.

Comment: @BenVoigt Thanks for your input. In the case of having a rendering engine(which would be platform specific), will this "class" contain the main eventloop(in the case of X11) or window callback procedure(in the case of Win32) that would also handle the user input? If not, which class should contain the main event loop? It becomes inevitable that you'd end up with a fair amount of code for the platform dependent components, which I'm trying to minimize...

Comment: @user1054465: X11 and Win32 are actually very similar as far as event processing goes.  In both, you create your window, register callbacks (ok, in Win32 it's just one WndProc function for all events), and then run an event loop.  Painting is done in the handler for `WM_PAINT` on win32, I know X11 has an equivalent event but I can't remember the name.  And then you have a timer callback which forces a redraw.  Your paint callback needs to have the dc or gc.  And for a game, that might as well be a global (maybe a global instance of a class that holds it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Games are rarely intrinsically platform dependent. Simple games can be made with GLUT and it is very easy to maintain two versions of the code using #defines. The callbacks are handled by GLUT.

In this way GLUT will enable you write nearly the same code for Windows and Linux. (Because issues such as making the context are already handled by GLUT).

Unless your project is to explicitly re-write GLUT, I recommend you stick with it and get on with writing your game.

Comment: This isn't really a platform dependency question, but rather an OOP question. I find it really hard to separate out the Windowing/Rendering/User Input Handling components and write OO code when I have to rely on one single library(Xlib or GDI) to do all of them.

Comment: The people who wrote GLUT already wrote in functions for things like keyboard input. In this way you never need to touch system specific libraries such as GDI or Xlib. The folks that worked on GLUT already figured that out, so that you can concentration on coding in C++ and writing OpenGL rendering routines.

Comment: I'm not writing this game to make profit out of it, but merely to learn how one would approach this in organizing the components in an OO fashion given minimum set of libraries. I understand that if you use all the fancy libraries it will make life easier and you'll be able to make a better game, but that is not my objective here.

Comment: If this is the case then you should be especially interested in GLUT as it is the implementation of exactly what you described. Good Luck!